Closed Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) Formula for Pauli Matrices
Refined Question: Decomposition of Rotations in $SU(2)$
In reference to the group compostion law of elements of $SU(2)$, cf. e.g. eq. (13) in Qmechanic's answer here, one thing I do not fully understand is how to decompose a given element of $SU(2)$ (such as a rotation $e^{i \lambda (\mathbf{n} \cdot \boldsymbol{\sigma})}$) into two rotations. Specifically:

Can the respective angles $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and axes $\mathbf{n}_1, \mathbf{n}_2$ of the two rotations be chosen arbitrarily as long as they satisfy the composition law for the given element?

Or is there a systematic or unique procedure to determine these parameters, depending on the given element?



See section 4 in my Phys.SE answer here.


Yes, of course! 2. By above there is an infinity of  $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and axes $\mathbf{n}_1, \mathbf{n}_2$ of   two rotations,   chosen arbitrarily as long as they satisfy the composition law for the given element. For SU(2), the CBH formula is irrelevant, since the exponentials have a simple closed form.


Thanks for the answer!
